# How to style this <li> so as the second row of the sentence to start just below the beginning of it and not below bullet?

Tags: html, css

My question is how can I make the second row of a li to start right below the beginning of the sentence and not below the arrow?

```
<ul class="arrow-list">
    <li>Clear and consistent brand identity</li>
    <li>+47.08% Increase in website registrations</li>
</ul>

.arrow-list li {
  color: #0054a6;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: block;
}
.arrow-list li:before {
  font-family: 'ElegantIcons';
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  content: "\39";
  color: #0054a6;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 18px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you consider enclosing the data in the li inside a block? (div, span)? That should keep all that stuff together without affecting the left side of the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give `position:relative` to `li` (the parent in this case) and then replace `position:relative` for `position:absolute` in `li:before` (which is the child) so the arrow can move in anyway you want.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> **Absolute**
>
> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
>   specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to
>   the containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins,
>   they do not collapse with any other margins.

Just a quick note, you were using `content:\39` which results in `9` if you want to achieve the *double arrow* then you should use `content:\bb`

```css
/*demo styles - width is to force break line*/
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing:border-box
}
.arrow-list {
  width: 260px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
/*end demo styles*/

.arrow-list li {
  color: #0054a6;
  margin: 0 0 4px 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left:0%;
  padding: 2% 0 2% 7% /*demo styles */
}
.arrow-list li:before {
  font-family: 'ElegantIcons';
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  content: "\bb";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: #0054a6;
  font-size: 18px;
/*  display: inline-block; not needed */
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 2%
}
```

```html
<ul class="arrow-list">
  <li>Clear and consistent brand identity</li>
  <li>+47.08% Increase in website registrations</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
.arrow-list li {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.arrow-list li:before{
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kz41hvfu/